EF Core SaveChanges error after explicit transaction
I have a code, which tries to do a certain first set of operations inside an explicit transaction, and then the rest of operations just normally.
The transaction goes okay, and gets disposed. Then when I try to make an update outside the now disposed transaction and call _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(), its throwing me this error:

SqlException: Cannot issue SAVE TRANSACTION when there is no active transaction

I don't want to use any transaction anymore. I think something has changed in the internal state of DbContext.
I have tried to clean the ChangeTracker, in hope it would reset the internal state, but it didn't work. Disposing isn't an option currently, as I'm using dependency injected scoped IUnitOfWork abstraction on top of the DbContext.
Using SQL Server and Entity Framework Core 8.
Idiomatic example code:
public async Task<Model> DoSomethingInTransactionAsync()
{
    using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    try
    {
        // Perform some operations
        var entity = new Model { Name = "TransactionEntity" };
        _dbContext.Models.Add(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Commit the transaction
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
        return entity;
    }
    catch
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
        throw;
    }
}

public async Task UpdateAnotherEntityAsync()
{
    // Call the method with the transaction
    var model = await DoSomethingInTransactionAsync();

    // Perform another operation without explicit transaction
    var anotherEntity = await _dbContext.OtherEntities.FindAsync(1);
    anotherEntity.Name = "UpdatedName";
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // **ERROR OCCURS HERE**
}


You aren't supposed to do anything with the context after calling Commit. Use a new context instead.

Side note: catch { await transaction.RollbackAsync(); throw; is unnecessary as disposing the transaction already handles that. You should also use await using var transaction =

The reason for using this transaction, is because it was the only way I could retrieve a database generated value on a table INSERT. Inserting and saving changes without explicit transaction, did not give me the value Im expecting. Do you recommend any other solution? @Charlieface

But why do you need UpdateAnotherEntityAsync outside the transaction, why not keep it all in one transaction?

Because for creating lets say a Product, I need to insert on 8 different tables. I'm only worried about the atomicity of the first 3 tables, and I don't want the other 5 tables inserts to even risk failing the whole transaction for any reason. I care the Product gets created with the 3 tables, even incomplete without the other ones. That is just how the business logic is in some words.

I tried your exact code as shown using .NET 8 + EF Core 8 and it just works 100%. No errors, the Model entity is added in the database, the OtherModel entity is updated in the database. The use of Transaction + Commit makes no difference for the test scenario (works with and without it). So you must be doing something that is different in your real program.

I’m voting to close this question because the problem is not reproducible with the given code.

There doesn't look to be any issue with your example code, so there is almost certainly a bug in your original code, or your simplification doesn't cover something about your actual scenario. I would be highly suspect of something not being awaited. If you want more fine-grained control over a DbContext scope then I recommend either using a Unit of Work / DbContextScope for operations you want to group, or a DbContextFactory to create a scoped instance for grouped vs. isolated operations rather than something like a single injected Scoped instance.

If an EF Core type has database generated fields, like ID values, then the context should take care of it without needing you to manually wrap everything in a transaction. Just set the navigation properties on the new instances before saving and EF Core will take care of populating the FK fields for you.... Unless you're trying to populate some kind of circular reference, in which case; sure save twice in a transaction. However you are probably ignoring an sql error, then trying to commit or rollback the transaction creates another error...
